# Is it possible to send requests to an LDAP server through an HTTP proxy?

Tags: ldap, http-proxy, tinyproxy

We use an HTTP proxy (tinyproxy) on a dedicated machine to be able to reach legacy services from our GKE cluster with a static IP address. I'm aware that this is not the best solution, but the requirements are set by the target environment on which we have no control, and this solution  works great for HTTP and SSH requests.

We now have the requirement to connect to an existing LDAP server, and in this case again do so from a static IP address. Is there a way to do this by sending requests to the LDAP server through the HTTP proxy?

Answer (score 1):

LDAP and HTTP are both application layer protocols and thus incompatible. I doubt tinyproxy supports LDAP proxying out of the box, but you could use a separate LDAP proxy.

A quick search reveals a few LDAP proxy products on the market. [OpenLDAP](https://www.openldap.org/), an open source LDAP server, also can be used as a proxy. Some examples of this can be found ([1](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1509203627-OpenLDAP-Proxy----Introduction), [2](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/OpenLDAP_as_proxy_to_AD)).